# Cannot open python files with double click

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to open my python files with a double click. I normally open them in anaconda prompt which uses the powershell file found in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0. I tried using open with and navigating to this file, however then the promt window opens and immediately closes... the script should run continuously.

I also tried opening it with the "python (command line)" file which I found in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7 I cannot open the location of that file for some reason using right click> open file location, however I tried to open my script using this but again the same thing happens.

It is frustrating as I need to close and open my scripts often. Each time I have to load up anaconda prompt, type in python and drag the file, and than press enter.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have installed Python 3.7 btw that I installed with ana and am trying to avoid reinstalling python as I have so many npm installs done that I did not keep a log of.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open file/folder in other IDE like vscode, pyCharm or text editor.
Open IDE first after that click on file menu and select open option.Browse the file/folder and select it.

Comment: I can open it using visual studio code and run it there fine.

Comment: Problem with opening in visual studio is I can only run 1 script in the python window... and I have to let it load and than press play in visual studio code... this takes a lot of time when I am opening and closing scripts very frequently and I need to do so quickly.